# Gitlab pages: verify domain ownership

Tags: dns, gitlab

This might look like a duplicate but i can't seem to find the answer to this question on other similar threads.

I've been trying to verify my custom domain on gitlab pages but it keeps giving the 'failed to verify domain ownership' error. My DNS settings are set [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqQBh.png). On gitlab i've added the domain in the settings/pages tab.

When going to the domain now, it only shows a gitlab 404, which is the exact same as just entering '52.167.214.135' in the address bar. I've waited a few days for the verification.

What am i doing wrong, and how can i fix it?

(Note: The TTL of 1min is only temporary for testing purposes)

Comment: Are you sure you are creating the record at the proper DNS host? It is common for people to have external DNS, but to create records at the domain registrar. If you tell us the domain name and your DNS hosting we can check if the record is resolved and if the name servers are pointed to correct servers.

Comment: For anyone seeing this question after Aug 2018, note the IP address for GitLab pages has changed: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/08/28/gitlab-pages-update/

Answer (score 2):

The Gitlab documentation for setting a personal domain is wrong. If you want to set to your page the `www.foo.bar` subdomain Gitlab give you this entries to add in your DNS file.

```
www.foo.bar CNAME free_zed.gitlab.io.
_gitlab-pages-verification-code.www.foo.bar TXT gitlab-pages-verification-code=776615a3e132b0f5a6638c7e26e59084
```

This cannot work, you had to use these entries instead :

```
www CNAME free_zed.gitlab.io.
_gitlab-pages-verification-code.www TXT gitlab-pages-verification-code=776615a3e132b0f5a6638c7e26e59084
```

See [Gitlab pages issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/32779)